# inserting data from multile form when button click

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am working on project which have zend framework.In that I want to create different form for different languages.which insert same data but language is different in mysql database table.I have no idea how can I insert all forms data in table by only submitting  one form.in short I want a logic for inserting data from all different languages form just by submitting one language form.

Comment: Read this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/performance.localization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one form, guide your user by passing different language parameters.  for example

```
http://127.0.0.1/controller/action/lan/en
```

Then show different `Form Label` to your user using the parameter you got (In your view)

```
$lan = $this->_getParam("lan");
if($lan == "en"){
    $this->view->labelForInput1 = "English";
    $this->view->labelForInput2 = "Another English Label";
}
else{
// define different language label here
}
```

Finally using a hidden input to pass the language choice into your form 
Thus when you want to show the result to user, you will able to know which language you should use.